# Getting text from span without an id

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to get the text inside a span in a web browser, the problem is that the span does not have a id.

This is the code I've tried:

```
        var findhuv1 = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span").OfType<HtmlElement>()
                        .Where(html => html.GetAttribute("class").Equals("huv1")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
        label14.Text = findhuv1;
```

This is the HTML code on the webpage:

```
<span class="huv1">6436347</span>
```

The problem is that my code only returns with an error:

```
    System.NullReferenceException
System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<TSource>(...) returned null.
```

I need help to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I don't have access to edit the HTML codes on the webpage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Couldnt figure out the right way to get the text whit that